# How do I access to private member variable from another class whose member variable is instance of first class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

First of all, thank you for helping.
I have been learning C, and just started studying C++ recently.

I am trying to figure out the new object-oriented concept.

So for example,

```
class Contact{
    private:
        char name[30];
        char birthday[10];
        char email[30];
        char phone[20];
   public:
        char* getname();
        char* getbirthday();
        char* getemail();
        char* getphone();
        void setname(char* x);
        void setbirthday(char* y);
        void setemail(char* z);
        void setphone(char* w);
};
class ContactArray
{

    private:
    friend class contactArray;
        int max_size;
        Contact **contact1;
    public:
        friend class contactArray;
        ContactArray(int num)
        {
            int i;
            max_size = num;
            contact1 = new Contact*[max_size];
            
            for(i = 0; i <max_size ;i++)
            {
            contact1[i] = new Contact();
            }
            
        }
};
```

This is the classes I am using right now but if I try to access to "char name[30]" my program will stop excatly where the "getname()" function is used. So more briefly,

```
ContactArray *contactArray;
contactArray = new ContactArray(6);
```

if I make instance like this then if I create public method of ContactArray called read_data,

```
void ContactArray::read_data(char* filename)
{
.........
....

fgets(str, BUFSIZE,fp);
ptr = strtok(str,";")
contact1[i]->setname(ptr);

printf("%s", contact1[i]->getname());//program stops here-----> here

}
```

if I try to check if "setname(ptr)" worked fine by getname() it stops so I cannot check.
other things such as reading file or tokenizations are working fine cause I can check them
my apology using C based function, I am still learning C++ but please ignore them.

I think it has something to do with memory allocation but not quite sure why.
Help me

---

```
    char* Contact::getname()
{
           char* n;
            strcpy(n,name);
            
            return n;
}
```

this is the getter function

Comment: Try changing `contact1[i]->getname(ptr)` to `contact1[i]->getname()`.

Comment: This shouldn't "stop". This should refuse to even compile. You do not have a getname function that takes an argument. In future, if you could copy-paste the actual error message into your questions it will help people to answer.

Comment: oh that was a typo it is supposed to be getname() not getname(ptr). my bad

Comment: And it is just that I did not mention the definition of getname. I have it I will edit it one sec

Answer (score 0):

The "n" pointer in your Contact::getname() function is not initialized when you pass it to strcpy().
That means strcpy() will try to copy the string to whatever memory address happened to be in the "n" pointer at that moment of execution (that address could be anything since the variable is not initialized, and it will most likely cause a crash). You should allocate new memory with `n = new char[30];` before the strcpy().

Better yet, you should use the `strncpy()` function instead, otherwise your program will do a buffer overrun if the "name" string is not null-terminated (which may also be happening here).

Since you mentionned you're learning C++ comming from C, I'd suggest you look into the std::string class, which handles pretty much all the memory management hassle for you.

Comment: That was wonderful explanation. Thank you so much wow.